# switch pages navigation bar php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to link my pages so I can switch from when to another through navigation bar but it's not working and keeps reloading none stop without a result.

in my html nav bar :

```
<div id="topnav">
<a href="?page=index.php">Home</a>
<a href="?page=About.php">About</a>
<a href="?page=Contact.php">Contact</a>
</div>
```

in my index.php

````
  if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
    include "index.php";
  } else {
    switch ($_GET['page']) {
      case "About":
        include "About.php";
        break;
      case "contact":
        include "Contact.php";
        break;
      default:
        include "index.php";
    };
  }
  ?> ```
````

Comment: Seems like endless recursion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Switch cases don't seem to match with the page parameters...

```
// amending the case values
switch ($_GET['page']) {
  case "About.php":
    include "About.php";
    break;
  case "Contact.php":
    include "Contact.php";
    break;
  default:
    include "index.php";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all the pages are in the same directory. Try this

```
<div id="topnav">
<a href="index.php">Home</a>
<a href="About.php">About</a>
<a href="Contact.php">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I used both of you guys answer and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the example on how to check if the file exists and then include it in the navigation...
simply use index.php?nav=Something

```
<?php
if ($_GET['nav']) {
    $nav = strtolower($_GET['nav']);
}
else {
    $nav = "main";    
}
$folder = "./nav/";
$extens = ".php";
$mainfl = $folder."main".$extens;

switch($nav) {
    case "about":
        $filenm = $folder.strtolower($nav).$extens;
        if (file_exists($filenm)) {
            include($filenm);
        } else {
            include($mainfl);
        }
        break;
    case "download":
        $filenm = $folder.strtolower($nav).$extens;
        if (file_exists($filenm)) {
            include($filenm);
        } else {
            include($mainfl);
        }
        break;
    case "products":
        $filenm = $folder.strtolower($nav).$extens;
        if (file_exists($filenm)) {
            include($filenm);
        } else {
            include($mainfl);
        }
        break;
    default:
        include($mainfl);
}
?>
```